# How to publish content from website to facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I have a website that generates information about a person after they fill out some inputs. I want people to be able to share this information with their friends on facebook. I've searched the facebook API links on facebook.com but can't seem to find a clear cut way to do this. I know there are plugins on Wordpress that allow visitors to share an article on facebook, so I figured it would be somewhat easy to implement on a regular site.

I have share/like buttons but it doesn't share a particular "article" that I might want to share. Right now it's sort of a general "like this page and checkout the website" type deal.

Comment: In what language is your website? Basically what you need is to create a Facebook developer account (free on https://developers.facebook.com/), create a Facebook app (no coding needed for that, you do that on FB website) to get an app Id and secret key. Download the SDK for your language (PHP,...) or the Javascript one if there is none for your language and use the provided sample to understand how inter-acting with FB and users works. There are a couple of tutorials (ex. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

try this, maybe it will help :

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php? u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'facebook-share-dialog','width=626,height=436');return    false;">facebook</a>
```